# Can Cesium be used in iOS development?

Tags: ios, xcode, cesiumjs

Can Cesium projects be used in iPhone apps? Does anybody know if its possible to use Cesium 3D Maps Technology in Xcode?
I am trying to work on a project for aircrafts but I'm very curious as to if this could be done on an iPhone, iPad, or Mac.. is it coded in XCode?

Comment: Load your HTML and JS in a web view (`WKWebView`). Interactions between the HTML/JS and the rest of the (native) app may be suboptimal, though, but it really depends on what you are trying to achieve. Using a hybrid app development environment such as Cordova or Ionic might be an option as well.

Comment: I currently have a live server that public running it but was wondering if someone preferred the application, what would be the easiest way to transform it from a website to an iOs App for iPhone

Comment: It all depends what you have on the server. If you are just serving static files (html, js, css, images), you should be able to wrap it in a Cordova app pretty quickly. Likewise if you have static pages which load all their data through web services. If you have server-side scripts serving pages, it’s going to be quite a bit more work, unless you go for the brute “embed a web view” approach (but that’s not allowed by Apple for the App Store). Of course this is all based on your existing content being responsive.